# Opening PDF forms in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, document-library, pdf

I have a document library that has PDFs stored.  I have the system to open in the client application.  When I open the document, it opens in the PDF file.  However, some users try to open it, it opens up in the browser.

I need for everyone to open these docs up in the application to be able to electronically sign the document.  What am I missing?

Comment: And those users have the client installed and matched the application extension PDF to that client?

Comment: Are they all using the same browser? Different browsers have different setups on what opens what and how by default.

Answer (score 4):

**Try to make sure the following:**

- In your document library setting > Advanced setting,  make sure that the **Opening Documents in the Browser** is set to `Open in the client application`.
- Make sure that each user has Adobe PDF client application installed.
- Make sure the web application **Browser File Handling** setting is set to `Strict` not `Permissive` in central administration > manage web application.
- The last thing, remove the PDF extension from the allowed MIME type list by running the following:

  ```
  $webApp = Get-SPWebApplication("http://webappurl")
  $WebApp.AllowedInlineDownloadedMimeTypes.Remove("application/pdf")
  $webApp.Update()
  ```